# Is it possible to mount an .iso file to the CD/DVD device of an VMware Workstation using command line?

Tags: windows, virtualization, virtual-machines, command-line-interface, vmware-workstation

I'm on Windows and using VMware Workstation as my virtualization tool. Normally, if I want to mount an .iso file to my guest VM, I can do it through the GUI:
[image]

I want to know if it's possible to do the same thing using command line tools? I checked its built-in tool `vmrun` but didn't find anything interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you can install inside the VM the PowerCLI's tool.

In PowerShell with the VMWare PowerCLI could do the trick if so.

> Get-VM -Name VM_NAME | Get-CDDrive| Set-CDDrive -Connected $true
> -IsoPath '[DataStoreName] iso_folder\file.iso'

In worst case if you dont need that ISO at boot, just use Windows Powershell to mount your ISO; that way;

> Mount-DiskImage -PassThru c:\iso\Server2012.iso